# Centering a marker at the center of a div

Tags: leaflet, maps, mapbox, openstreetmap

I have a div that i am using to hold a leaflet map. It currently looks like this

[image]

I want the marker to be at the center or near center of the div so that its visible always even the marker is further left and out of view or out of view in any direction.

Currently my code looks like this

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 18);


    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 50,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    L.marker([52.573921, -0.250830]).addTo(mymap)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup. <br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();

    mymap.fitBounds([52.573921, -0.250830]);
    mymap.setView([52.573921, -0.250830]);
    mymap.setZoom(18);
```

I get the error bounds are not valid.

I would like my marker to be at least here

[image]

Comment: Try this command, mymap.panTo(new L.LatLng(52.573921, -0.250830));

Comment: This works when i zoom to 17. Is there any other way to center?

Comment: try without code mymap.fitBounds([52.573921, -0.250830]);

Comment: i still get the error bounds are not valid

Comment: Thanks @Sameera I got it working, by managing my height of the div,before the height was too long and thus the center was always far below what a user can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
mymap.panTo(new L.LatLng(52.573921, -0.250830));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that `fitBounds()` takes a `L.latLngBounds` as its argument, and you're passing it a single `L.point`.

You need a different way of panning the map to your desired centre location - maybe `map.panTo()` or `map.flyTo()` if you want pan/zoom animation.